# Why are some web pages are displaying in tablet view when on mobile?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, responsive

When viewing our website on mobile devices (only tested on android), some pages display correctly with correct mobile view, such as the homepage, and others display a tablet view, which is much further zoomed out but still have the burger menu.

Correct view: https://www.onlyve.com/ (https://photos.app.goo.gl/YAnNY6J3Fv8CVHk6A)
Incorrect view: https://www.onlyve.com/vegan-product-category/food-drink/brownies/ (https://photos.app.goo.gl/Huq25C2NBMHmYa6w8)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this is in the `<head>` of all your pages:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: This worked perfectly. I've never needed to use this before. Any ideas why this was required? Thanks for your support.

Comment: It's because of mobile devices and retina pixels, and how they render media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag